# Masstransit - how to avoid consuming the same message again?

Tags: masstransit

I am using MassTransit v8.0.8 libraries with Azure Service Bus and EF Core. The below is how I have set up my service. One of the consumers run a little longer as it process a huge number of records, say 50K. While it is processing them, after 5 minutes or so, my consumer seems to consume the same message (the same correlation id) again. So, can I please get some advice as to how I can avoid this duplicate consumption?

```
 services.AddMassTransit(busRegistrationConfigurator =>
        {
            busRegistrationConfigurator.SetKebabCaseEndpointNameFormatter();

            busRegistrationConfigurator.UsingAzureServiceBus((registrationContext, busFactoryConfigurator) =>
            {
                busFactoryConfigurator.ConfigureEndpoints(registrationContext);
                busFactoryConfigurator.Host(busConnectionString);
            });

            foreach (var implementation in consumerImplementations)
            {
                busRegistrationConfigurator.AddConsumer(implementation);
            }

            busRegistrationConfigurator.AddEntityFrameworkOutbox<TDbContext>(outboxConfigurator =>
            {
                outboxConfigurator.UseSqlServer();
                outboxConfigurator.UseBusOutbox();
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set a combination of `LockDuration` and `MaxAutoRenewDuration` such that the message remains locked for the duration.

Also, if you want to use the transactional outbox with your consumer, you need to configure that as well.

```cs
x.AddConfigureEndpointsCallback((context, name, cfg) => 
{
    cfg.UseMessageRetry(r => r.Intervals(100, 500, 1000, 5000, 10000));
    cfg.UseEntityFrameworkOutbox<TDbContext>(context);

    if(cfg is IServiceBusReceiveEndpointConfigurator sb)
    {
        sb.LockDuration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
        sb.MaxAutoRenewDuration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(37);
    });
});
```

Comment: Many thanks, this works for me.