MassTransit - MessageLockExpiredException - Longer executing message fails on completion
I have a MassTransit Consumer that should on average complete its messages in 15-20 minutes.
I am using Azure.ServiceBus.Core transport.
The message will successfully operate through all configured business logic, but the message instead faults on a MassTransit.MessageLockExpiredException after the message completes.

I've tried setting MaxAutoRenewDuration and LockDuration
                x.UsingAzureServiceBus((context, cfg) =>
                {
                    cfg.Host(hostContext.Configuration["AzureServiceBus_ConnectionString"]);
                    cfg.UseConsumeFilter(typeof(ConsumeContextFilter<>), context);
                    cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(context);
                    cfg.MaxAutoRenewDuration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
                    cfg.LockDuration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
                });


Same answer as a previous question, using a configure endpoints callback to actually set the properties on the receive endpoint and not the default bus endpoint. https://stackoverflow.com/a/77283035/1882

You need to configure the properties on the receive endpoint, not the bus.
x.AddConfigureEndpointsCallback((context, name, cfg) => 
{
    if(cfg is IServiceBusReceiveEndpointConfigurator sb)
    {
        sb.LockDuration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
        sb.MaxAutoRenewDuration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
    });
});


I see that you are trying to set the lock duration to 30 minutes, let me explain why this is not possible.
The maximum lock duration for a service bus messages is 5 minutes, see this section of the service bus documentation. The way you can get around this is to renew the lock before it expires, that is, before the 5 minutes has passed.
